# Using apply on pandas dataframe with strings without looping over series

Tags: string, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, apply

I have a pandas DataFrame filled with strings. I would like to apply a string operation to all entries, for example `capitalize()`. I know that for a series we can use `series.str.capitlize()`. I also know that I can loop over the column of the Dataframe and do this for each of the columns. But I want something more efficient and elegant, without looping. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `stack` + `unstack`
`stack` makes a dataframe with a single level column index into a series.  You can then perform your `str.capitalize()` and `unstack` to get back your original form.

```
df.stack().str.capitalize().unstack()
```

Comment: note that this will be non performant compared to apply over columns as this copies more (and infers dtypes)  and is not as cache friendly  - so YMMV (that said it IS a nice idiom if you have all object data)